# Cannot get SpacingAfter to work on image with iTextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

Hi I would like to add some extra space after a image in my iTextSharp generated pdf document. But for some reason whatever I try to do it will not prevent my text from wrapping

[Example image](http://twitpic.com/5q0de1)

As you can see the "to read everyth..." does not indent like the rest

This is the codesnip that should do this:

```
var brevityBox = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance("http://" + domain + "/ImageGen.ashx?Text=" + brevityScore + "&FontSize=120&&FontStyle=Bold&Font=Calibri&Align=Center&image=/media/images/PDF/BrevityBox.jpg");
brevityBox.ScaleToFit(80f, 220f);
brevityBox.Alignment = Image.TEXTWRAP;
brevityBox.SpacingAfter = 460f;
doc.Add(brevityBox);

Chunk c3 = new Chunk(brevityText, FontFactory.GetFont("Verdana", 12, Font.NORMAL)); ;
Paragraph p3 = new Paragraph();
p3.IndentationLeft = 20;
p3.IndentationRight = 20;

p3.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
p3.Add(c3);
doc.Add(p3);
```

Just to prove the point the SpacingAfter is 460 points.

```
IndentationRight
```

works fine

Any ideas?

Comment: I tried a bunch of things and unfortunately I can't seem to find a way to do what you want it to do. In theory your code should work. If you do find a solution please post it here.

Comment: Thanks chris for the effort. I'll post any findings here

Answer (score 0):

I believe that iTextSharp is not even using the SpacingAfter property.  I modified the method

```
iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfDocument.Add(iTextSharp.text.Image image){}
```

to this:

```
if (imageEnd < 0 || imageEnd < currentHeight + image.ScaledHeight + diff + image.SpacingAfter)
{
    imageEnd = currentHeight + image.ScaledHeight + diff + image.SpacingAfter;
}
```

From v5.2.1 it was line 2244 in PdfDocument.cs